# LoadError: UndefVarError: @defVar not defined

Tags: julia

I have a piece of code about JuMP. When I run it ,it says that LoadError: UndefVarError: @defVar not defined. I have tried using global forward or backward but both fails.

See:

```
function T1(w_func,grid_b,β,u,z)
            # objective for each grid point
                for j in 1:cp.Nb
                b = grid_b[j]
                choice1 = Model(solver=GLPKSolverLP()) 
                @defVar (choice1, a >= 0)
                @setObjective(choice1, Max, u(a) + cp.β * (w_func.((b*(1+cp.r)+cp.w-a) .* cp.z[i])))
                results1 = solve(choice1)
                Tw1 = getObjectiveValue(choice1)
                c_choice1 = getValue(x)
                return Tw, σ
                end
            end      

LoadError: UndefVarError: @defVar not defined
in expression starting at In[44]:37

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ :0
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1094

thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using an outdated code. Look at the [fresh documentation](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/v0.21.9/tutorials/Getting%20started/getting_started_with_JuMP/) and make sure you have installed the latest versions of libraries and Julia.

In short, `@defVar` and `@setObjective` were replaced by `@variable` and `@objective` correspondingly.

```
function T1(w_func,grid_b,β,u,z)
    # objective for each grid point
    for j in 1:cp.Nb
        b = grid_b[j]
        choice1 = Model(solver=GLPKSolverLP()) 
        @variable(choice1, a >= 0)
        @objective(choice1, Max, u(a) + cp.β * (w_func.((b*(1+cp.r)+cp.w-a) .* cp.z[i])))
        results1 = solve(choice1)
        Tw1 = getObjectiveValue(choice1)
        c_choice1 = getValue(x)
        return Tw, σ
    end
end
```